# How to pre-allocated volumes on a specified volume server to balance volumes?

Tags: seaweedfs

I have a master server `M1` and three volume servers `V1`,`V2`,`V3` in my cluster. And I want to add three more volume servers. `V1`,`V2`,`V3` already have 30 volumes and newly added `V4`,`V5`,`V6` have no volumes.

Now I want new files to be stored in `V4`,`V5`,`V6`, but after some time I see no new volumes appears under `V4`,`V5`,`V6`. Of course, `volume.balance` should solve balance it, but the url to files will change. The url are like `V1address:V1port/somefid` and may become `V5address:V5port/somefid` after balance.

If I pre-allocate volumes, the pre-allocated ones are randomly allocated at all volume server. How to pre-allocated volumes only on `V4`,`V5`,`V6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volumes are expected to move around. Use the volume id to lookup the location, and then resolve to the volume server address.

To explicitly create volumes on specific servers, see https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs/wiki/Optimization#increase-concurrent-writes

```
curl http://localhost:9333/vol/grow?count=12&dataCenter=dc1&rack=rack1
curl http://localhost:9333/vol/grow?count=12&dataCenter=dc1&rack=rack1&dataNode=node1
```